# Apps Permission Request XML for Workflow, and Rest Workflow Help Please

Tags: workflow, permissions, rest

The documentation on msdn is pure junk if you ask me, for setting up App permissions in a Workflow. Here is the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

They were following a nice example of the app domain, and redirect url, and then they put this scope example in there.
it says "sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web",
so what is this content business, is this some app permission on the content db somehow?!?

Or should it be "sharepoint/sites/sitecollection/web"?

Well, hold-on. Because earlier they mentioned about starting a workflow app on the SITE COLLECTION level, why does this example throw in a web url in the example?
... but then the pictured diagram has the /web DROPPED from

```
Step number 7
in the Figure: Looking up an App Id
```

Wtf is going on?
My question is I have "domain.xxxx.org/sites/workflows" Site collection, and I want to enable workflows to use app steps across the entire site collection ( this may not be possible, and I can do it for every site that's okay)

Then "http://domain" resolves, and is what the user will be logged in under, does this matter anywhere when I'm making rest calls in my workflows?